# Is there any reference on how accurately people can answer comparison questions?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling, metacognition

Have any lab experiments taken place on how accurately people answer comparison questions such as "Do you prefer A to B? or "Which one do you prefer? A or B?"

Comment: How would you define accuracy?

Comment: Yes, lots, way too many to cover here.  I recommend narrowing down what it is that you want to know, or this question should be closed as too broad.  In a classic example, [Wilson et al (1993)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0146167293193010) asked students if they prefer poster A or B, and tested accuracy using a follow-up satisfaction interview some time later.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg  Thanks a lot for the answer. So I am mainly interested to know if people can answer comparison questions "Do you prefer A to B?" where A and B are bundles of items. By accuracy, I Mean, If I give them a list of their values for each item and perhaps some complementarities between items. Can they then accurately answer the question based on these?

Comment: @BryanKrause By accuracy, I Mean, If I give them a list of their values for each item and perhaps some complementarities between items. Can they then accurately answer the question based on these?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include those details, and maybe provide an example?  I expect that accuracy will depend on how complicated the criteria are.